# Preg-match filenames with hypens

Tags: php, preg-match, filenames, preg-grep

How do I check filenames with preg_match in PHP?

**Filename = 2.pdf**

It should also match if another file is called `2-2.pdf` or `2-3.pdf`.

It's the Id before the hypen. It dont need to check the `.pdf` file extension.

```
$id = 2;
$list = scandir("D:/uploads/");
$list = preg_grep("/^".$id."$/", $list);

foreach ($list as $file)
{
    echo $file . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regular expression

```
/^2[-.]/
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/aJ7cK0/1

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/^$id(?:-\d+)?/
```

**Explanation:**

```
/        : delimiter
^        : begining of strig
$id      : the id defined earlier
(?:      : begining of non capture group
    _    : a dash
    \d+  : one or more digits
)?       : end of group, optional
/        : delimiter
```

**Usage:**

```
$list = preg_grep("/^$id(?:-\d+)?/", $list);
```